# Dojo combo box specify label and value

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to follow [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/selects_using_stores/) example on how to setup a combo-box using dojo, but wondering how one can specify name and value programmatically. The example presented uses the same values for label and value - which is probably not one wants in most cases.

```
{
    "identifier": "abbreviation",
    "label": "name",
    "items": [
        { "abbreviation": "AL", "name": "Alabama" },

        ... other 48 states here ...

        { "abbreviation": "WY", "name": "Wyoming" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the case. Looking at http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/selects_using_stores/demo/ProgSelect.html (and even your posted code) shows different values for the labels.

Comment: did you take a look at this link? http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/selects_using_stores/

Comment: Yes, it appears to me that it allows for what you are looking for...

Comment: no it dosen't. It only list labels not values

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to replace the hard coded list in the example then here is what you have to do. In the above scenario items was used to specify the data which is an array (abbreviations and names) of values.

In your case you will need to get the data / object from your data source. Once you have that data/object expose it to the view. Once this has been done you can now do the following structure.

You store is really your items above however stateStore will be a java script array which contains the data from your data source.

```
stateStore = [{"abbreviation": "AL", "name": "Alabama"},
               ... other 48 states here ...,
              { "abbreviation": "WY", "name": "Wyoming" }]

// create FilteringSelect widget, populating its options from the store
 var select = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
              name: "stateSelect",
              placeHolder: "Select a State",
              store: stateStore
              }, "stateSelect");
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:50%;float: left;">
 <h1>dijit.form.Select</h1>
 <label for="stateSelect">State:</label>
 <div id="stateSelect"></div>
</div>
```